# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "type: 'Buffer'"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Tried to create a new user on my web application without realizing there was already a user in my database with the same username. For some reason, this boundary case broke my app and now everytime I try to go to the home page, I get:

> (node:14649) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ type: 'Buffer',
>     data: [ 89, 243, 30, 231, 66, 69, 45, 56, 123, 65, 153, 72 ] }" at path "_id" for model "users"
>   (node:14649) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

What makes this question unique from the other questions here on stackoverflow is the fact that the type is 'Buffer'. None of the other questions had that specific issue. I have no idea how a buffer was created when I am not using them at all in my database or node server.

Here is the duplicate error message that occurred just before the buffer error:

> { MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: crud2.users
>   index: username_1 dup key: { : "lightbeam" }
>       at Function.MongoError.create (/Users/*/Desktop/coding/apps/thequoteapp/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
>       at toError (/Users/*/Desktop/coding/apps/thequoteapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:139:22)
>       at /Users/*/Desktop/coding/apps/thequoteapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:668:23
>       at handleCallback (/Users/*/Desktop/coding/apps/thequoteapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:120:56)
>       at /Users/*/Desktop/coding/apps/thequoteapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:465:9
>       at handleCallback (/Users/*/Desktop/coding/apps/thequoteapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:120:56)
>       at resultHandler (/Users/*/Desktop/coding/apps/thequoteapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:413:5)
>       at /Users/*/Desktop/coding/apps/thequoteapp/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)   name: 'MongoError',   message: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection:
>   crud2.users index: username_1 dup key: { : "lightbeam" }',   driver:
>   true,   code: 11000,   index: 0,   errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error
>   collection: crud2.users index: username_1 dup key: { : "lightbeam" }',
>   getOperation: [Function],   toJSON: [Function],   toString: [Function]
>   }

Here is my user schema:

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let UserSchema = new Schema ({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: [true, "This username is taken."],
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: [true, "This email is already being used."],
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    favorites: []
})

// first parameter is the name of the collection! If does not exist, will be created!
const User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema)
module.exports = User
```

And here is the get request defined in my route.js file:

```
/* route handling for HOME PAGE. */
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("req.user value: ", req.user)
    Quote.find({})
    .exec((err, results) => {
        err ? console.log(err) : res.render('index', { quotes: results })
    })
})
```

And finally the post request to create a new user:

```
router.post('/signup/users', (req, res, next) => {
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username field cannot be empty.').notEmpty()
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username must be between 4-30 characters long.').len(4, 30)
    req.checkBody('email', 'The email you entered is invalid, please try again.').isEmail()
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email address must be between 4-100 characters long, please try again.').len(4, 100)
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password must be between 8-100 characters long.').len(8, 100)
    // req.checkBody('password', 'Password must include one lowercase character, one uppercase character, a number, and a special character.').matches(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.* )(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{8,}$/, 'i')
    req.checkBody('passwordMatch', 'Password must be between 8-100 characters long.').len(8, 100)
    req.checkBody('passwordMatch', 'Passwords do not match, please try again.').equals(req.body.password)

    // Additional validation to ensure username is alphanumeric with underscores and dashes
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username can only contain letters, numbers, or underscores.').matches(/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$/, 'i')

    const errors = req.validationErrors()

    if(errors) {
        res.render('signup', {
            errors: errors
        })
    } else {
        let password = req.body.password
        bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
            user = new User()
            user.username = req.body.username
            user.email = req.body.email
            user.password = hash

            user.save((err, result) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    User.find({}).sort({ _id:-1 }).limit(1)
                    .exec((err, newuser) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                        } else {
                            userId = ObjectId(newuser.id)

                            // logins user through passport function
                            req.login(userId, (err) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log("Login error: " + err)
                                } else {
                                    res.redirect('/home')
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(next)
                }
            })
        })
    }
})
```

I have tried restarting the nodemon and the mongodb server, and I have tried using:

```
kill -2 `pgrep mongo`
```

to clear any and all instances of the mongodb server. Please help!

Comment: `User.find({}).sort({ _id:-1 }).limit(1)` still returns an `Array`. So `newuser.id` cannot possibly be referring to an `ObjectId` value. Where are you importing `ObjectId` as you are using with `ObjectId(newuser.id)` from? Because that should be failing horribly, but is seemingly returning a `Buffer`. Pretty sure you can still `User.findOne().sort({ _id: -1 })`. But at any rate, just get the **one** result and use it's "already typed ObjectId` value of `_id` instead of the current incorrect code.

Comment: I imported ObjectId at the top of the file with `const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;`. `User.findOne()` does not have any sorting capabilities, so that is the reason I used `User.find()` instead. I have created around 12 users so far with this code that are currently stored in my database, but the moment that duplicate error was returned, the application seems to have permanently broken.

Comment: Your core problem us `newuser` is **NOT** a "single document". You either want `newuser[0]._id` or use `User.findOne().sort()`. You should still be able to apply the sort there since it "should" be essentially a wrapped method. If not, then use the `[]`  notation to get the single element as shown. **DO NOT ATTEMPT TO MANUALLY CAST**. This is your next error. This is basically what I already said, but hopefully this time it sinks in what you are doing wrong.

Comment: After an hour of debugging, I figured out that you are exactly right. After dropping my collections and indexes completely, I removed ObjectId and instead retrieved the id using newuser[0]._id, which successfully logged me in through passport. I guess I just don't understand how it is an array, yet when I console log the array `newuser`, it displays as an object literal in the console. Nonetheless, my errors have been resolved, all thanks to you. So I sincerely thank you for your help.